# parallel processing in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5,000,000 rows in my dataframe. In my code, I am using iterrows() which is taking too much time. To get the required output, I have to iterate through all the rows . So I wanted to know whether I can parallelize the code in pandas.

Comment: Vectorize before parrallelize!!!  You can vectorize in panda by avoiding iterrows().  If you are using iterrows at all, you probably haven't spent enough time learning pandas basics.  Do that first.  After that, ask a specific question showing your code along with some sample data.

Comment: @JohnE I actually needed to use iterrows as well, similarly having to process 10s of millions of rows in a file, and there was a need to aggregate keys for counting. To process the huge dataframe, it had to be split into chunks, which poses a problem for aggregation by keys (since they might appear in separate chunks). Hence the approach was to use an external state store (e.g. redis) for aggregation, by performing row-wise writes for each row's key into the state store for counting, which meant the use of iterrows(). Unless there are other ways to aggregate huge dataframes by vectorization?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a webpage I found that might help: http://gouthamanbalaraman.com/blog/distributed-processing-pandas.html

And here's the code for multiprocessing found in that page:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

LARGE_FILE = "D:\\my_large_file.txt"
CHUNKSIZE = 100000 # processing 100,000 rows at a time

def process_frame(df):
    # process data frame
    return len(df)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reader = pd.read_table(LARGE_FILE, chunksize=CHUNKSIZE)
    pool = mp.Pool(4) # use 4 processes

    funclist = []
    for df in reader:
        # process each data frame
        f = pool.apply_async(process_frame,[df])
        funclist.append(f)

    result = 0
    for f in funclist:
        result += f.get(timeout=10) # timeout in 10 seconds

    print "There are %d rows of data"%(result)
```

Comment: Will the data order be retained? Some f's will finish faster but the get() will return in order, won't it?

Answer (score 9):

In 2022, you DO NOT need to implement `multiprocessing` by yourself. Actually `pandarallel` provides an **one-line solution** for the parallel processing in pandas. Just follow the next two step:

First, install it

```
pip install pandarallel [--upgrade] [--user]
```

Second, replace your `df.apply(func)` with `df.parallel_apply(func)`, and you'll see it work as you expect!

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel

pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True) # initialize(36) or initialize(os.cpu_count()-1)

#### old code:
# df.apply(func)
#### new code:
df.parallel_apply(func) 
#### and then you can see that CPU cores are called to run your pandas op~
```

More ops~

| Without parallelization | With parallelization |
| --- | --- |
| df.apply(func) | df.parallel_apply(func) |
| df.applymap(func) | df.parallel_applymap(func) |
| df.groupby(args).apply(func) | df.groupby(args).parallel_apply(func) |
| df.groupby(args1).col_name.rolling(args2).apply(func) | df.groupby(args1).col_name.rolling(args2).parallel_apply(func) |
| df.groupby(args1).col_name.expanding(args2).apply(func) | df.groupby(args1).col_name.expanding(args2).parallel_apply(func) |
| series.map(func) | series.parallel_map(func) |
| series.apply(func) | series.parallel_apply(func) |
| series.rolling(args).apply(func) | series.rolling(args).parallel_apply(func) |

Enjoy your dinner :D

Answer (score 4):

This code shows how you might break up a large dataframe into smaller dataframes each with a number of rows equal to `N_ROWS` (except possibly for the last dataframe) and then pass each dataframe to a process pool (of whatever size you want, but there is no point in using anything larger than the number of processors you have). Each worker process returns the modified dataframe back to the main process which then reassembles the final result dataframe by concatenating the return values from the worker processes:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp


def process_frame(df):
    # process data frame
    # create new index starting at 0:
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
    # increment everybody's age:
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        df.at[i, 'Age'] += 1
    return df


def divide_and_conquer(df):
    N_ROWS = 2 # number of rows in each dataframe
    with mp.Pool(3) as pool: # use 3 processes
        # break up dataframe into smaller daraframes of N_ROWS rows each
        cnt = len(df.index)
        n, remainder = divmod(cnt, N_ROWS)
        results = []
        start_index = 0
        for i in range(n):
            results.append(pool.apply_async(process_frame, args=(df.loc[start_index:start_index+N_ROWS-1, :],)))
            start_index += N_ROWS
        if remainder:
            results.append(pool.apply_async(process_frame, args=(df.loc[start_index:start_index+remainder-1, :],)))
        new_dfs = [result.get() for result in results]
        # reassemble final dataframe:
        df = pd.concat(new_dfs, ignore_index=True)
        return df



if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Name": ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Jane', 'June', 'Sally', 'Mary'],
        "Age": [10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 60, 70],
        "Sex": ['M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']
    })
    print(df)
    df = divide_and_conquer(df)
    print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Name  Age Sex
0    Tom   10   M
1   Dick   20   M
2  Harry   30   M
3   Jane   40   F
4   June   40   F
5  Sally   60   F
6   Mary   70   F
    Name  Age Sex
0    Tom   11   M
1   Dick   21   M
2  Harry   31   M
3   Jane   41   F
4   June   41   F
5  Sally   61   F
6   Mary   71   F
```

Comment: Is it possible to modify code so that process_frame function returns two data frames, let's one with increased age, another with decreased age? so the return would like smth return df1, df2.

Comment: @errenmike1806 Why not? You could modify  `process_frame` to make a copy of the passed `dataframe` with `df2 = df.copy(deep=True)` and then subtract 1 instead of adding 1 using `df2`. Then the function would return a tuple `(df, `df2)` and the main process would build up two aggregate `dataframe` instances.