# Speeding up derived feature calculation in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have the following workflow in a Python notebook

1. Load data into a pandas dataframe from a table (around 200K rows) --> I will call this `orig_DF` moving forward
2. Manipulate `orig_DF` to get into a DF that has columns <Feature1, Feature 2,...,Feature N, Label> --> I will call this derived DF ```ML_input DF`` moving forward.  This DF is used to train a ML model
3. To get `ML_input DF`, I need to do some complex processing on each row in `orig_DF`. In particular, each row in `orig_DF` gets converted into multiple "rows" (number unknown before processing a row) in `ML_input DF`

Currently, I am doing (code below)

1. `orig_df.iterrows()` to loop through each row
2. Apply a function on each row. This returns a list.
3. Accumulate results from multiple rows into one list
4. Convert this list into `ML_input DF` after the loop ends

This works but I want speed this up by parallelizing the work on each row and accumulating the results. Would appreciate pointers from Pandas experts on how to do this. An example would be greatly appreciated

Current code is below.

Note: I have looked into using `df.apply()`. But two issues seem to be

1. `apply` in itself does not seem to parallelize things.
2. I don't how to make apply handle this `one row converted to multiple row` issue (any pointers here will also help)

**Current code**

```
def get_training_dataframe(dfin):
    X = []
    for index, row in dfin.iterrows():
        ts_frame_dict = ast.literal_eval(row["sample_dictionary"])
        for ts, frame in ts_frame_dict.items():
          features = get_features(frame)
          if features != None:
            X += [features]

   return pd.DataFrame(X, columns=FEATURE_NAMES)
```

Comment: Can you check this question. It talks about "parallel processing in pandas python" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054321/parallel-processing-in-pandas-python/36055566

Comment: what does `get_features` function do? also could you share the first few rows of your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what optimizations are possible without having example data and without knowing what `get_features()` does.

The following code ought to be equivalent (I think) to your code, but it attempts to "vectorize" each step instead of performing it all within the for-loop.  Perhaps that will offer you a chance to more easily measure the time taken by each step, and optimize the bottlenecks.

In particular, I wonder if it's faster to combine the calls to `ast.literal_eval()` into a single call.  That's what I've done here, but I have no idea if it's truly faster.

I recommend trying [line profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) if you can.

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

def get_training_dataframe(dfin):
    frame_dicts = ast.literal_eval('[' + ','.join(dfin['sample_dictionary']) + ']')
    frames = chain(*(d.values() for d in frame_dicts))
    features = map(get_features, frames)
    features = [f for f in features if f is not None]
    return pd.DataFrame(features, columns=FEATURE_NAMES)
```