# How to use concurrent.futures in a Pandas dataframe with the apply function?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I have been trying to parallelize my code and spent some time researching Dask, Pandarallel but they did not work for one reason or the other so I am now looking at implementing concurrent.futures.

This is what my problem statement looks like:

> 1)def do_stuff( (self.param1, self.param2) ,  abs(self.param3)):
>
> value = multi-step equation of self.param1, self.param2,
> self.param3 (this takes over 2-5 minutes per row)
> return value.
>
> 2)df['value'] = df.apply(lambda row:  do_stuff((self.param1,
> self.param2) ,  abs(self.param3)) , axis =1)

Since my df has over 1500 rows and each row takes about 2 mins to process over a single core, I believe I would benefit from multiprocessing. I am starting to understand how pool and ProcessPoolExecutor work but I am stuck on the syntax on how to use df.apply with multiprocessing. I went through the examples online but I could not find any that deal with the apply function using a dataframe.

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    future = executor.submit(pow, 323, 1235) ------> modify this line to process a df.apply

write back the result to a df.
```

Could someone help me with a simple syntax or point me in the right direction? I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parallel processing in pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054321/parallel-processing-in-pandas-python)

Comment: Hi @Laurent! thank you for your reply. I did see that post but not quite what I was looking for.

Basically, I just wanted to duplicate how Dask works with : https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.apply.html

In other words, wanted to use .apply instead of going through each row in the dataframe.

A senior co-worker told me it can't be done so I just ended up doing as your link suggests so take my upvote :)