# Getting dataframes from ThreadPoolExecutor tasks

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor . submit() to process pandas dataframe calculations in parallel but when i'm using pd.concat() after the wait method:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, ALL_COMPLETED
import pandas as pd

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)
tasks = [executor.submit(lambda: pd.DataFrame()) for x in range(40)] ### not my code, just simulation

task_results = wait(tasks, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)[0]
pd.concat(task_results)
```

it's raised

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'concurrent.futures._base.Future'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

but if I do

```
task_results = [t.result() for t in task_results]
```

it's raised

```
*** TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

how can i get the dataframes inside task_results variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parallel processing in pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36054321/parallel-processing-in-pandas-python)

Comment: @eshirvana I already managed to solve. Thks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my error was when i passed a function to executor.submit()
I was doing

```
executor.submit(my_custom_func(my_slice_of_dataframe))
```

but the correct is:

```
executor.submit(my_custom_func, my_slice_of_dataframe)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function to your pool, not a dataframe instance.

This works (python 3.11.3):

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait, ALL_COMPLETED
import pandas as pd

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20)
tasks = [executor.submit(lambda : pd.DataFrame()) for x in range(40)] ### not my code, just simulation

task_results = wait(tasks, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED).done
pd.concat( t.result() for t in task_results)
```

Comment: sorry bro, this is just a demo. I already passed a function